# DNS server is not responding - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet, dns

This morning when I turned my PC on, there was a yellow marker on my network icon. I tried troubleshooting and got the following error:

```
DNS server is not responding
```

I am connected directly to my home router along two other PCs that work perfectly. I cannot ping the router or any of the other PCs on the network. I tried through command prompt all the "fixes" I found online (like flush, release, renew etc.). But none of this worked.

I also logged in to Safe Mode and the icon was not there and I was able access the internet with no problems. I run a malware check and an antivirus scan and both showed no problems.

I also tried public DNS like OpenDNS and the problem still persisted. Restarted, disabled the network cards but again no luck.

Also, it might be worth to mention that this is a wired connection, not wireless but all the rest of the computers on the network anyway (both wired and wireless).

Comment: Is the connection light on at both ends? What happened when you tried to ping the router?

Comment: If you mean the network cables, yes I double checked them and the internet works in safe mode so it's not a cable problem. I'm at work at the moment and can't check but i think it was that the host is unreachable. Also trying to access the router's web-interface times out.

Comment: Are you using static IP or DHCP. Type ipconfig in command promt and check your IP

Comment: Using DHCP. My computer IP and the default gateway seem correct.